# SQL insert reverse pair with join table

Tags: sql, h2

I have a problem to create the correct SQL command to create the missing reverse pair in my table structure.

I have following two tables:

Table A:

```
aId | bId
----------
1  | s1
2  | s2
3  | s3
4  | s4
```

Table B

```
bId | aId
----------
s1  | 3
s1  | 2
s2  | 1
s2  | 3
s3  | 2
s4  | 2
```

Now there is a missing entry in table B which is s3 -> 1 and s2 -> 4.

I am trying to insert the missing entry in table B but I am not sure how to do it.

The result should be:

```
bId | aId
----------
s1  | 3
s1  | 2
s2  | 1
s2  | 3
s2  | 4 <-- added missing entry
s3  | 2
s3  | 1 <-- added missing entry
s4  | 2
```

I know that I can insert data with a following select for example:

```
INSERT INTO B (aId, bId)
SELECT ...;
```

But I am not sure how to create the request to only add the missing entry with the correct Ids. I think that I have to join the table a in some way.

Comment: How do you know what the `bID` value is for the missing rows?

Comment: The bID is defined in table A. Each entry in table A has a unique bID. So there is a entry s1->3 in table B. But the revert entry with s3 (bId) -> 1 (aId) is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Select for full list (all A and B table values including missing ones) would look like

```
SELECT
  ISNULL(a.bId, b.bId) AS bId,
  ISNULL(a.aId, b.aId) AS aId
FROM Table_A a
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_B b  ON a.aId = b.aId  AND a.[bId] = b.bId
ORDER BY ISNULL(a.bId, b.bId), ISNULL(a.aId, b.aId)
```

So for insert into Table_B

```
;
WITH CTE_full AS
(SELECT  ISNULL(a.bId, b.bId) AS bId,  ISNULL(a.aId, b.aId) AS aId
 FROM Table_A a
 FULL OUTER JOIN Table_B b  ON a.aId = b.aId  AND a.[bId] = b.bId
)
INSERT INTO Table_B (aId, bId)
SELECT    aId,    bId
FROM CTE_full
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM Table_B b2 
                 WHERE b2.bId = CTE_full.bId AND b2.aId = CTE_full.aId)
```

Exchange Table_B with Table_A in Insert/where and you can populate table A with a similar query

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE(aId INT,  bId VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES
(1  , 's1'),
(2  , 's2'),
(3  , 's3'),
(4  , 's4')

DECLARE @TableB TABLE(bId VARCHAR(5),  aId INT)
INSERT INTO @TableB VALUES
('s1', 3),
('s1', 2),
('s2', 1),
('s2', 3),
('s3', 2),
('s4', 2)

--INSERT INTO @TableB (bId, aId)
SELECT A1.bId, A2.aId FROM @TableB B1
    INNER JOIN @TableA A1 ON A1.aId = B1.aId
    INNER JOIN @TableA A2 ON A2.bId = B1.bId
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM  @TableB T WHERE T.aId = A2.aId AND T.bId = A1.bId)
```

Result:

```
bId   aId
----- -----------
s2    4
s3    1
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test for H2, but this works for ypur sample data by using similar functions in Postgresql:

```
insert into tableb(bid, aid)
select concat(substring(t.bid from 1 for 1), t.aid), substring(t.bid from 2)
from tableb t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tableb
  where aid = substring(t.bid from 2) and bid = concat(substring(t.bid from 1 for 1), t.aid)
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ws7iic2CWh3ftC413Kx98n/2).

```
| bid | aid |
| --- | --- |
| s1  | 2   |
| s1  | 3   |
| s2  | 1   |
| s2  | 3   |
| s2  | 4   |
| s3  | 1   |
| s3  | 2   |
| s4  | 2   |
```